# Atlas creation of single feature

Tags: qgis, atlas, map-book

I am trying to create an atlas which should have one individual feature of a shapefile in each layout.. i.e. 10 polygons of a shapefile should have 10 layouts which only focus on that particular polygon and should not contain even a bit of any other polygon in QGIS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this steps:

1. Create a print Layout (insert the map),
2. Create the Atlas - Nr#1 in the attached print,
3. Define the layer you want to see (in your case the Polygon),
4. Define the column in the attribute table you want to see,
5. Enable the atlas view,
6. For better perspective add a text with the column name (Example: insert
   expression > [% "LAYER" %]),
7. Use the arrows to navigate around the entities,
8. In the right map (Map2) I just added the overview of the left one
   (Map1),
9. Export the atlas.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]